# Why Geometric distribution has different expectations but the same variance?

Tags: statistics

Geometric distribution: $$ f_X(k) = p (1 - p)^{k-1}, \quad k = 1,2,3,\cdots $$  The expectation:

$$ 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k p (1 - p)^{k - 1}  \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k-1} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (k - 1) p(1-p)^{k - 1} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty k p(1-p)^k \\
&= 1 + (1 - p) \sum_{k=1}^\infty k p(1-p)^{k - 1} \\
&= 1 + (1 - p) \mathbb{E}(X)
\end{align}
$$

Solving for the expectation, we get $\mathbb{E}(X) = 1/p$.

Another version of Geometric distribution: $$ f_X(k) = p (1 - p)^k, \quad k = 0, 1,2,3,\cdots $$

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k p (1 - p)^{k}  \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty kp(1-p)^{k}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)p(1-p)^{k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k}\\
&= (1-p)\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)p(1-p)^{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k}\\
&= (1 - p)\mathbb{E}(X) +\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k} \\
&= (1 - p)\mathbb{E}(X) +\sum_{k=0}^\infty p(1-p)^{k}-p \\
&= (1 - p)\mathbb{E}(X) +1-p \\
\end{align}
$$

from where we get $$\mathbb{E}(X) = (1-p)/p$$

For the variance we also have:

$$ 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X^2) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 p (1 - p)^{k - 1}  \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k p(1-p)^{k-1} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (k^2 - k) p(1-p)^{k - 1} \\
&= \mathbb{E}(X) + (1 - p) \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k^2 + k) p(1-p)^{k - 1} \\
&= \mathbb{E}(X) + (1 - p) \mathbb{E}(X) + (1 - p) \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 p(1-p)^{k-1} \\
&= \frac{2 - p}{p} + (1 - p) \mathbb{E}(X^2)
\end{align}
$$

Solving for the expectation, we get $\mathbb{E}(X^2) = (2 - p) / p^2$.

Finally,

$$ \mathbb{V}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2 = \frac{2 - p}{p^2} - \frac{1}{p^2} = \frac{1 - p}{p^2} $$

For the variant version of Geometric distribution: $$ f_X(k) = p (1 - p)^k, \quad k = 0, 1,2,3,\cdots $$
$$ 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X^2) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2 p (1 - p)^{k}  \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 p(1-p)^{k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)^2 p(1-p)^{k+1}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2 p(1-p)^{k+1}+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty k p(1-p)^{k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty p(1-p)^{k+1}\\
&= (1-p)\mathbb{E}(X^2)+2(1-p)\mathbb{E}(X)+(1-p)\\
&= (1-p)\mathbb{E}(X^2)+2(1-p)^2/p+(1-p)\\
&= (1-p)\mathbb{E}(X^2)+\frac{2(1-p)^2}{p}+\frac{p(1-p)}{p}\\
&= (1-p)\mathbb{E}(X^2)+\frac{2-3p+p^2}{p}\\
\end{align}
$$
We get $$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \frac{2-3p+p^2}{p^2}$$
And then the variance:
$$ \mathbb{V}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2 = \frac{2-3p+p^2}{p^2} - \frac{(1-p)^2}{p^2} = \frac{1 - p}{p^2} $$

Why Geometric distribution has different expectations but the same variance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the two distributions are linked in the following way

$$Y=X-1$$

Thus using expectation property you get that

$$E(Y)=E(X)-1$$

That is

$$E(Y)=\frac{1}{p}-1=\frac{1-p}{p}$$

But, using variance property,

$$V(Y)=V(X-1)=V(X)$$